# Flexbox — Ignore wrapper for child elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container that contains x elements, where each contains y children.

I'm trying to have the container space divided equally according to the children instead of the parents.

Currently what happens is:

{ [ 2 children ] [ 5 children ] [ 3 children ] }

The [] blocks are currently the same width, so it's spacious for the first one (only has 2 children), but cramped for the middle one.

I need wrappers for styling purposes, but can't seem to get the division of space to be based on the children instead of 'parent equally then children equally'.

I have not specified width for anything, just `flex: 1 0`, and the number of children is not static, so I can't use explicit widths.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 1000px;
}

wrap,
wrap *,
p {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

wrap {
  height: 100px;
}

wrap,
container,
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

container,
container div,
container div span {
  flex: 1 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

span,
p {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<wrap>
  <span>Flex Element Here</span>
  <container>
    <div>
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>C</span>
      <span>D</span>
      <span>E</span>
      <span>F</span>
      <span>G</span>
      <span>H</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>I</span>
      <span>J</span>
      <span>K</span>
    </div>
  </container>
  <span>Another Flex Element Here</span>
</wrap>
<p>A-B & I-K are roomy, while C-H is cramped. Ideally, space is divided so that these letter-boxes have the same width, while being wrapped. Number of letters is dynamic, so fixed-widths cannot be used.</p>
```

Comment: Trying to figure out your goal here. Not clear. If you can find a way to clarify, maybe adding images of your desired layout, that may help.

Comment: Pretty sure you would need JS for this since you're styling parents based on children...and CSS can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, each child in your container needs their own flex properties to achieve what you need ie control over how much space they take up. So they need ID's or classes to be able to target them.

```
<wrap>
  <span>Flex Element Here</span>
  <container>
    <div id="group1">
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
    </div>
    <div id="group2">
    ...
    <!-- and so on -->
```

Second, you need to analyze each group contents and adjust the CSS flex accordingly.

In no particular language...

> if group items <= 2 then set css flex to "flex: 1"
>
> if group items >= 5 then set css flex to "flex: 5"
>
> else set css flex to "flex: 2.5"

How you make up this spread of numbers is up to you; it's simply a ratio. To keep it simple, you could go with primary numbers that match the group item count e.g. if item count is 3, then flex: 3. You can use decimals too, for more fine-grained control e.g. two items = "flex: 0.2".

In any case, such processing needs to be done either on the back-end or front-end, or both, it's up to you.

**For a static page...**
You do this server-side, before sending the page to the client, using PHP or whatever your server language is. Analyze the content, and adjust the CSS rules accordingly.

**For a dynamic page...**
Use Javascript to analyze the content and adjust the CSS accordingly. For example, if you get data from a server via AJAX, then have a function check how many items are in a group and sets a new CSS rule accordingly. Anyways you probably still want to have a server-side function doing this for the initial page load (when the user first loads the page).

If your content does not change dynamically, then you should really not use Javascript to do this because all you're doing is making your page download longer and have slower performance on the client side.

Below is a code snippet with flex properties on each child group. You still need to decide how you want to adapt the CSS rules.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 1000px;
}

wrap,
wrap *,
p {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

wrap {
  height: 100px;
}

wrap,
container,
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

container,
container div,
container div span {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

#group1 {
 flex: 2; 
}

#group2 {
  flex: 5;
}

#group3 {
  flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<wrap>
  <span>Flex Element Here</span>
  <container>
    <div id="group1">
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
    </div>
    <div id="group2">
      <span>C</span>
      <span>D</span>
      <span>E</span>
      <span>F</span>
      <span>G</span>
      <span>H</span>
    </div>
    <div id="group3">
      <span>I</span>
      <span>J</span>
      <span>K</span>
    </div>
  </container>
  <span>Another Flex Element Here</span>
</wrap>
<p>A-B & I-K are roomy, while C-H is cramped. Ideally, space is divided so that these letter-boxes have the same width, while being wrapped. Number of letters is dynamic, so fixed-widths cannot be used.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get exactly equal columns with `flex-grow` because it's link to space remaining, not width. [CSS Tricks has a good explanation here.](https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/#article-header-id-4) That said if you want roughly columns you can use flex-grow like this:

1. You'll need to somehow set `flex-grow` on the flex-containers.
2. To minimize the annoyance with this create some class helpers.`.has-2-items {flex-grow: 2}` and place that on the container.
3. `Margin: auto;` on items should ensure proper spacing.

The only way I know of to do this in an exact way is to use explicit widths or place the children in the same container.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wibjorn/qxhsv1fm/)